# When using Auth0 I am unable to use Angular2 sample after migarting it to Angular4

Tags: authentication, auth0, angular

I am trying to apply auth0 sample for angular under this link https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/ but with no success. I upgraded to Angular 4. Whenever I try to click "Log In" link the Lock Widget is displayed with an error as: **`Something went wrong. Please contact technical support.`**
**I am using angular-cli with the following versions:**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.7.4
os: win32 x64
npm: 4.1.2
```

**And here is angular project's "dependencies" after upgrade it from v2 to v4:**

```
{
  "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
  "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
  "toastr": "^2.1.2",
  "typescript": "^2.2.1",
  "zone": "^0.3.4",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
```

**..\ng2auth>npm ls --depth 0**

```
ng2auth@0.0.0 ..\ng2auth

+-- @angular/compiler-cli@4.0.0 invalid
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@4.0.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.2.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.8.5

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.0.0, required by angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.0.0, required by angular2-jwt@0.1.28
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/http@^2.0.0, required by angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/http@^2.0.0, required by angular2-jwt@0.1.28
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12, required by angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21
npm ERR! peer dep missing: zone.js@^0.6.25, required by angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21
npm ERR! invalid: @angular/compiler-cli@4.0.0 ..\ng2auth\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli
npm ERR! invalid: typescript@2.2.1 ..\ng2auth\node_modules\typescript
```

Pls help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to 4.0.0, and i'm using Auth0.

I have no problem whatsoever clicking the Log In.

You can refer to my [code](https://github.com/faxad/cartify/tree/upgrade/4-0-0) on github.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will give it a try.

Comment: You are right. It works just fine. My problem was related to providing unsupported language option as 'ar' for Arabic language which is definitely another story .. Many Thanks!